# Menu button in Swift using UIkit

Tags: swift, button, menu, uikit

How can I recreate this type of menu in Swift using UIkit? Is it possible to play the same animation as well?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5kXC.jpg

Comment: it's iOS 14 Pull Down menus
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/pull-down-menus/

Comment: you can check here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/menus_and_shortcuts/adopting_menus_and_uiactions_in_your_user_interface